# java.lang.illegalstateexception attempt to re-open an already-closed object sqlitequery prblem

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-intent, android-asynctask

I execute a simple insert query into database.
But I get the exception as shown in the title.
Please, help me.

Code is bellow.

public void insertAutoAlbumDetails(String setId, String albumid,
            String Type, String albumName) {

```
    String query = "INSERT INTO "
            + ALBUM_DETAILS
            + "("
            + ALBUM_ID
            + ","
            + ALBUM_NAME
            + ","
            + ALBUM_TYPE
            + ","
            + USER_ID
            + ","
            + ALBUM_SETID
            + ") SELECT \""
            + albumid
            + "\",\""
            + albumName
            + "\",\""
            + Type
            + "\",\""
            + AppPreferences.getAppPreferences(context).getString(
                    AppConstants.USER_ID, "")
            + "\",\""
            + setId
            + "\" WHERE NOT EXISTS "
            + "("
            + "SELECT 1 FROM "
            + ALBUM_DETAILS
            + " WHERE "
            + ALBUM_ID
            + "=\""
            + albumid
            + "\" AND "
            + USER_ID
            + "=\""
            + AppPreferences.getAppPreferences(context).getString(
                    AppConstants.USER_ID, "") + "\")";

    this.Query(query);//// i get exception on this line.
}
```

Getting the following exception...

```
02-11 18:11:35.370: W/System.err(26820): java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/com.app.quirl/databases/canvera.sqlite
02-11 18:11:35.370: W/System.err(26820):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
02-11 18:11:35.370: W/System.err(26820):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1648)
02-11 18:11:35.370: W/System.err(26820):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
02-11 18:11:35.370: W/System.err(26820):    at com.app.quirl.db.GetDB.Query(GetDB.java:50)
02-11 18:11:35.370: W/System.err(26820):    at com.app.quirl.db.AlbumDetailsDao.insertAutoAlbumDetails(AlbumDetailsDao.java:119)
02-11 18:11:35.370: W/System.err(26820):    at com.app.quirl.GetAutoCountService.uploadImages(GetAutoCountService.java:108)
02-11 18:11:35.370: W/System.err(26820):    at com.app.quirl.GetAutoCountService.access$0(GetAutoCountService.java:62)
02-11 18:11:35.370: W/System.err(26820):    at com.app.quirl.GetAutoCountService$startUploadImage.doInBackground(GetAutoCountService.java:56)
02-11 18:11:35.370: W/System.err(26820):    at com.app.quirl.GetAutoCountService$startUploadImage.doInBackground(GetAutoCountService.java:1)
02-11 18:11:35.370: W/System.err(26820):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)    
02-11 18:11:35.370: W/System.err(26820):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-11 18:11:35.370: W/System.err(26820):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-11 18:11:35.370: W/System.err(26820):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-11 18:11:35.370: W/System.err(26820):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
02-11 18:11:35.370: W/System.err(26820):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
02-11 18:11:35.370: W/System.err(26820):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Your database already Closed then even you tried to insert data into database table..You must re-open this and insert data.

Answer (score 0):

exception said : you are trying to using already closed connection to insert that value. make sure connection is open to database before inserting.

Answer (score 0):

My problem ended up being that in `onCreate()`, I was calling `db.close()` after executing `db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE)`.

`onCreate` is automatically called after `dbHelper.getReadableDatabase()`.

This caused it to crash because then it went to retrieve all the values from the database with an already-closed object. Once I removed `db.close()` from `onCreate`, it all worked.

You would probably be calling `dbHelper.getReadableDatabase()` instead, but is that helpful?